# rounded corner using images

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below approach would be very older one but still & it might be very simple for an experienced people.

I have created one rounded corner panel with shadow using Photoshop. And I have sliced into three images

a)  leftpanel
   b)  centerpanel
   c)  rightpanel

Here is my coding for css

```
.leftpanel
{
    background:url('../images/panelleft.png') no-repeat;
    float:left;
    width:19px;
    height:285px;
}
.centerpanel
{
    background:url('../images/panel_center.png') repeat-x;
    height:285px;
}
.rightpanel
{
    background:url('../images/panel_right.png') no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    width:9px;
    height:285px;
}
```

And here is my html code for the same

```
<div style="width:300px;">
    <div class="leftpanel">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="centerpanel">
        heading
        <div class="rightpanel">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The output was showing wrongly

left & center is coming perfectly but the right image was not showing

Kindly help me

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Comment: Why don't you do it with CSS?

Comment: Your `rightpanel` is **inside** your `centerpanel`

Comment: ...also be careful when using this approach because if your center panel is too long, your corners will be ruined. That's why there are sometimes 8 images. 1 for each corner and 1 for each edge

Comment: `border-radius` isn't helpful?

Comment: No, because I want in ie7 also

Comment: IE7 market share is very low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `:after` and `:before` for doing that like this:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/frH37/2/) (working on IE7 too)

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel">
    <div id="left"></div>
    header
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.panel:before, #left
{
    content:"";
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcs8F.png') no-repeat;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:-9px;
width:9px;
height:100px;
}

.panel
{
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOPT5.png') repeat-x;
height:100px;
width:200px;
position:relative;
margin:0 9px;
}

div.panel:after, #right
{
content:"";
background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sXib.png') no-repeat;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:-9px;
width:9px;
height:100px;
}
```

create your background and slice it to three part: left, right, center.

here is my sliced background:

[image]
[image]
[image]

then set `width` and `height` to your `:before` and `:after`.
note that you need to set `margin-left` or `margin-right` equal to the element width. in this case it is `9px;`

## update:

changed CSS and HTML for working in IE6 and IE7.

Comment: Can anyone help me how to add an image in fiddle  so I can explain more on the same

Comment: hi @Mohsen thank you so much for the above help but exactly what i want is i need a header in that rounded corner with silver gradient color and shadow overall

Comment: @user2690456 you need to change the background. create your background and slice it like i did.

Comment: thank you so much it is working fine but my concern is whether it will work in ie7

Comment: hi @Mohsen thank you so much for the above immediate response the thing is it is not working in ie7 

can you please help me to work in ie7

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `position:absolute;` from `.rightpanel` to display it properly.

Also, make the below changes to your HTML.

```
<div style="width:300px;">
   <div class="rightpanel">&nbsp;</div>       
   <div class="centerpanel">heading</div>
   <div class="leftpanel">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

If the above does not work, keep your `position:absolute;` from `.rightpanel` and just change the order of HTML as mentioned above.

Hope this helps.